# Access context from Apollo GraphQL mutation field directive

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I have an input type like this:

```
input PetGiraffe {
    name: String @addUserLastName
}
```

Inside the directive, I need access to the request's `context`, so that I can add the user's last name to the giraffe's name. Here's the relevant part of what I've got so far:

```
const addUserLastNameDirective = {
    typeDefs: gql`directive @addUserLastName on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION`,
    transformer: (schema: GraphQLSchema, directiveName = 'addUserLastName') => {
        return mapSchema(schema, {
            [MapperKind.INPUT_OBJECT_FIELD]: (fieldConfig, fieldName, typeName, schema) => {
                const directive = getDirective(schema, fieldConfig, directiveName)?.[0];
                if (directive) {
                    // Need context in here because the user is in the context.
                }
            },
        });
    },
};
```

For queries, I understand you can override the `fieldConfig.resolve` method and get access to the context that way. But if I try that with this mutation, it throws: `field has a resolve property, but Input Types cannot define resolvers`.

The closest I could find was [this](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-directives#enforcing-value-restrictions) from the `graphql-tools` docs, but that doesn't solve my problem of accessing the context.

Comment: Hi Zevgon, Have you found a solution?

Comment: No I've still got my hack to avoid the problem :( Might be worth a feature request at this point, it doesn't look like this is supported

Comment: This should be available. I got stuck here too

Comment: @Zevgon what's the hack you used?

Comment: @SubhamPasari I had to ditch the directive altogether, and put the logic into the mutation's resolver itself. Ugly but working